# second participant audio is not playing on first participant device when automatically join the room on page load

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

Second participant audio/video is not playing on first participant device.

condition: audio and video are set to off on joining room and join the room automatically when page load. if second participant unmute him/her self first then first participant can't listen the voice or see video.

we are facing this problem on project and but can share the project repo link, but I have created another codesandbox to demonstrate the same problem.

codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-ben-jvztxi

join the room by passing the token(get the same from twilio cli) in url.

ex https://jvztxi.csb.app?t=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTSzc2NzAzNWIxNTUwYjM1NGZkMThhOTAxNjJiOTQxZjE1LTE2ODM3ODg3NjIiLCJncmFudHMiOnsiaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJzYW5qYXkiLCJ2aWRlbyI6e319LCJpYXQiOjE2ODM3ODg3NjIsImV4cCI6MTY4Mzc5MjM2MiwiaXNzIjoiU0s3NjcwMzViMTU1MGIzNTRmZDE4YTkwMTYyYjk0MWYxNSIsInN1YiI6IkFDNDM5MjJhNmRiZWYyMWYzMjJjZTEyZDM5ZDcxZmFlOWMifQ.MmUUi4Wz_yM08bsqOQb4CSQqEa6Lxx2RcM0nk6xw5d1

Requesting for help.